# How to create and use image template with intervention image and Laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, intervention

I am using the [Intervention Image library](http://image.intervention.io/getting_started/installation#laravel) in my Laravel 5.2 app along with the [Image Cache plugin](https://github.com/Intervention/imagecache)

I have been using the predefined templates out the box with no issues like so:

```
{{ route('imagecache', ['template' => 'medium', 'filename' => 'image.jpg']) }}"
```

I have seen in the documentation that as well as the default sizes small, medium and large you can create image filters to create custom manipulations and define them as a template in the config file so that instead of medium I would pass my template name. The documentation references Image filters as a way to do this but it's a bit sketchy as to exactly how to do it. Does anyone know how you do it exactly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside `config/imagecache.php` there is a `templates` key, here you can add your own.

For example:

```php
'templates' => [
    // ...
   'x-large' => 'App\Filters\ExtraLarge',
   // ...
],
```

Then you would just need to create the class `App\Fitlers\ExtraLarge`.

Inside the `applyFilter()` method you can call any methods on the `$image` property according to the [documentation](http://image.intervention.io/use/filters).

```php
<?php

namespace App\Filters;

use Intervention\Image\Image;
use Intervention\Image\Filters\FilterInterface;

class ExtraLarge implements FilterInterface
{
    public function applyFilter(Image $image)
    {
        return $image->fit(1300, 1000);
    }
}
```

Then inside the `route` helper set the value of template to `x-large`

```php
{{ route('imagecache', ['template' => 'x-large', 'filename' => 'image.jpg']) }}
```